# Javascript Interval continues endless without conditions met

Tags: javascript, function, debugging, event-handling, intervals

```js
var counter;
var count = 0;

var equalsPressed = false;
var dritter = false;
var array = new Array();

window.onload = function() {
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName('zahlen')
  let i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    let y = x[i];
    x[i].addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
      add(this.className, this.value.replace(/\s/g, ''));
    }, true);
    //x[i].addEventListener(mousedown,function('Hi')
    x[i].onmousedown = debounce(function() {
      start(y.className, y.value.replace(/\s/g, ''));
    }, 200);
  }
}

function debounce(a, b) {
  return function() {
    let timer;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    booli = true;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      if (booli) {
        a();
      } else {
        clearInterval(counter);
      }
    }, b);
  };
}


function start(clicked_className, Zeichen) {
  counter = setInterval(function() {
    add(clicked_className, Zeichen);
    count++;
  }, 370);
}

function end() {
  booli = false;
  clearInterval(counter);
}


function Check(Eingabe) {
  // indexof=suche in "0123456789[]()-+*%/" nach den chars der eingabe(0 bis 1 kleiner als länge (also alle)) und schaue an welcher position im string diese sind.wenn position kleiner0(also nicht vorhanden)
  // dann return false, ansonsten alles gut
  var inhalt = "0123456789[]().-+*%/=e";
  for (var i = 0; i < Eingabe.length; i++)
    if (inhalt.indexOf(Eingabe.charAt(i)) < 0) return false;
  return true;
}


function Ergebnis() {
  var z = document.getElementById("Historie");
  z.style.display = "block";
  var ausg = 0;

  if (equalsPressed && Check(window.document.Rechner.Display.value)) {
    var o = window.document.Rechner.Display2.value;
    var p = window.document.Rechner.Display.value;
    p = p.replace("=", '');

    const chars = ["+", "-", "*", "/"];
    var last;

    for (const rechenarten of o) {
      if (chars.includes(rechenarten)) {
        last = rechenarten;
      }

    }
    //lastIndexOf zählt von hinten und fängt bei o.length - 1 also der letzten Position an
    //und sucht last, also die am weitesten hinten vorkommende der Rechenarten
    o = o.slice(o.lastIndexOf(last, o.length - 1), o.lenght);

    ausg = eval(p + o);

    ausg = ausg.toFixed(getDecimalPlaces(p));
    window.document.Rechner.Display.value = ausg;
    window.document.Rechner.Display2.value = window.document.Rechner.Display2.value + o;
    dritter = true;
  } else {
    var y = 0;
    var x = 0;

    if (Check(window.document.Rechner.Display.value))
      y = window.document.Rechner.Display.value;
    window.document.Rechner.Display2.value = y;
    ausg = eval(window.document.Rechner.Display.value);
    ausg = ausg.toFixed(getDecimalPlaces(y)); //
    window.document.Rechner.Display.value = "=" + ausg;
  }
}

function getDecimalPlaces(numb) {
  var highest = 0;
  var counter = 0;
  for (a = 0; a < numb.length; a++) {
    if (numb.charAt(a - 1) == ".") {
      do {
        counter++;
        a++;
      }
      while (!isNaN(numb.charAt(a)) && a < numb.length);
    }
    if (counter > highest) {
      highest = counter;
    }
    counter = 0;
  }
  return highest;
}


function add(clicked_className, Zeichen) {
  if (equalsPressed == false && clicked_className == 'zahlen') {
    window.document.Rechner.Display.value =
      window.document.Rechner.Display.value + Zeichen;
  } else if (dritter && equalsPressed && clicked_className == 'zahlen') {
    var array = new Array();
    array.push(window.document.Rechner.Display2.value + "=" +
      window.document.Rechner.Display.value);

    var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("Historie")
    var table = document.createElement('TABLE')
    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY')
    table.border = '0';
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);

    var td = document.createElement('TD')
    td.width = '275';
    td.style.textAlign = "right";
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[0]));

    tr.appendChild(td);
    myTableDiv.appendChild(table)


    window.document.Rechner.Display2.value = "";
    window.document.Rechner.Display.value = "";
    window.document.Rechner.Display.value =
      window.document.Rechner.Display.value + Zeichen;
    equalsPressed = false;

  } else if (equalsPressed && clicked_className == 'zahlen') {
    window.document.Rechner.Display2.value = "";
    window.document.Rechner.Display.value = "";
    window.document.Rechner.Display.value =
      window.document.Rechner.Display.value + Zeichen;
    equalsPressed = false;

  } else if (clicked_className == 'ops') {
    var x;
    window.document.Rechner.Display.value = window.document.Rechner.Display.value.replace("=", '');
    window.document.Rechner.Display.value =
      window.document.Rechner.Display.value + Zeichen;
    equalsPressed = false;
  }
}



function gleichPressed() {
  equalsPressed = true;
}


function backspace() {
  var abschneiden = window.document.Rechner.Display.value;
  for (var i = 0; i < abschneiden.length; i++) {
    var output = abschneiden.slice(0, -1);
    window.document.Rechner.Display.value = output;
  }
}

function ausgabe() {

  if (equalsPressed) {

  } else {

    array.push(window.document.Rechner.Display2.value +
      window.document.Rechner.Display.value);
    console.log(array);

    var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("Historie")
    var table = document.createElement('TABLE')
    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY')
    table.border = '0';
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);

    var td = document.createElement('TD')
    td.width = '275';
    td.style.textAlign = "right";
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[0]));

    tr.appendChild(td);
    myTableDiv.appendChild(table)
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, Geneva, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}

.button,
.ops,
.zahlen,
.sonst,
.istgleich {
  background-color: #A4A4A4;
  background: linear-gradient(240deg, grey, white);
  color: black;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: System, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.button:hover,
.zahlen:hover,
.sonst:hover,
.ops:hover,
.istgleich:hover {
  color: #2E2E2E;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  background: linear-gradient(30deg, darkgrey, lightgrey, grey);
  ;
}

.display {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: System, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}

#Historie {
  background: linear-gradient(30deg, silver, white, grey);
  ;
  border: 5px outset;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
}

#eins {
  background: linear-gradient(30deg, silver, grey, DimGray);
  ;
}

#zwei {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, silver, grey);
  ;
}

#tabelle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 235px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html onmouseup="end()">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Taschenrechner</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFE0" text="#000000">
  <form name="Rechner" action="" onSubmit="Ergebnis();return false;">
    <table id="tabelle" style="float:left" border="7" cellpadding="12" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td id="eins">
          <input type="text" name="Display2" class="display" readonly>
          <input type="text" name="Display" class="display" readonly></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="zwei">

          <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value="  7   " onmouseleave="end()">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value="  8   " onmouseleave="end()">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value="  9   " onmouseleave="end()">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="sonst" value="  &#171  " onClick="backspace()">
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value="  4   " onmouseleave="end()">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value="  5   " onmouseleave="end()">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value="  6   " onmouseleave="end()">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="ops" value="  +   " onClick="add(this.className,'+')">
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value="  1   " onmouseleave="end()">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value="  2   " onmouseleave="end()">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value="  3   " onmouseleave="end()">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="ops" value="  -   " onClick="add(this.className,'-')">
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value="  .   ">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value="  0   " onmouseleave="end()">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="istgleich" value="  =   " onClick="Ergebnis();ausgabe();gleichPressed()">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="ops" value="  *   " onClick="add(this.className,'*')">
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value=" ( ">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value=" ) ">
              </td>
              <td><input type="reset" class="button" value="  C  ">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="ops" value="  /   " onClick="add(this.className,'/')">
              </td>
            </tr>

          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>

  <div class="Historie" id="Historie" hidden="true">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Instruction___: doubleclick and hold

Im really really helpless in finding that bug tried to find where it originates, and build in couple of booleans so the loop only runs if theyre true but they were all false and it still continued running.

Im looking for a solution or a good way to adress the problem:(

What i found very noteworthy is that it only occurs when doing the needed keypresses fast, if done slower it doesnt result in that bug, also when done multiple times, it loops multiple times.

Comment: _"or a good way to adress the problem"_ - Create a [mcve]

Comment: thats what Im doing since "1 minute" or maybe a bit longer than id like to admit :D

Comment: please describe the problem you are having...

Comment: doubleclick  and hold it... it loops infinitely :( its supposed to stop when mouseup or buttonleave

Comment: Your `debounce` function is broken. The `let timer` is in the wrong scope.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just like Bergi said, your debounce function is broken. You need to initialize the `timer` variable outside the returned function.

This is your implementation:

```
function debounce(a, b) {
  return function() {
    let timer;
    clearTimeout(timer);
    booli = true;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      if (booli) {
        a();
      } else {
        clearInterval(counter);
      }
    }, b);
  };
}
```

And this is how you fix your bug:

```
function debounce(a, b) {
  let timer;
  return function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    booli = true;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      if (booli) {
        a();
      } else {
        clearInterval(counter);
      }
    }, b);
  };
}
```

```js
var counter;
var count = 0;

var equalsPressed = false;
var dritter = false;
var array = new Array();

window.onload = function() {
  let x = document.getElementsByClassName('zahlen')
  let i;
  for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
    let y = x[i];
    x[i].addEventListener('mousedown', function() {
      add(this.className, this.value.replace(/\s/g, ''));
    }, true);
    //x[i].addEventListener(mousedown,function('Hi')
    x[i].onmousedown = debounce(function() {
      start(y.className, y.value.replace(/\s/g, ''));
    }, 200);
  }
}

function debounce(a, b) {
  let timer;
  return function() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    booli = true;
    timer = setTimeout(function() {
      if (booli) {
        a();
      } else {
        clearInterval(counter);
      }
    }, b);
  };
}


function start(clicked_className, Zeichen) {
  counter = setInterval(function() {
    add(clicked_className, Zeichen);
    count++;
  }, 370);
}

function end() {
  booli = false;
  clearInterval(counter);
}


function Check(Eingabe) {
  // indexof=suche in "0123456789[]()-+*%/" nach den chars der eingabe(0 bis 1 kleiner als länge (also alle)) und schaue an welcher position im string diese sind.wenn position kleiner0(also nicht vorhanden)
  // dann return false, ansonsten alles gut
  var inhalt = "0123456789[]().-+*%/=e";
  for (var i = 0; i < Eingabe.length; i++)
    if (inhalt.indexOf(Eingabe.charAt(i)) < 0) return false;
  return true;
}


function Ergebnis() {
  var z = document.getElementById("Historie");
  z.style.display = "block";
  var ausg = 0;

  if (equalsPressed && Check(window.document.Rechner.Display.value)) {
    var o = window.document.Rechner.Display2.value;
    var p = window.document.Rechner.Display.value;
    p = p.replace("=", '');

    const chars = ["+", "-", "*", "/"];
    var last;

    for (const rechenarten of o) {
      if (chars.includes(rechenarten)) {
        last = rechenarten;
      }

    }
    //lastIndexOf zählt von hinten und fängt bei o.length - 1 also der letzten Position an
    //und sucht last, also die am weitesten hinten vorkommende der Rechenarten
    o = o.slice(o.lastIndexOf(last, o.length - 1), o.lenght);

    ausg = eval(p + o);

    ausg = ausg.toFixed(getDecimalPlaces(p));
    window.document.Rechner.Display.value = ausg;
    window.document.Rechner.Display2.value = window.document.Rechner.Display2.value + o;
    dritter = true;
  } else {
    var y = 0;
    var x = 0;

    if (Check(window.document.Rechner.Display.value))
      y = window.document.Rechner.Display.value;
    window.document.Rechner.Display2.value = y;
    ausg = eval(window.document.Rechner.Display.value);
    ausg = ausg.toFixed(getDecimalPlaces(y)); //
    window.document.Rechner.Display.value = "=" + ausg;
  }
}

function getDecimalPlaces(numb) {
  var highest = 0;
  var counter = 0;
  for (a = 0; a < numb.length; a++) {
    if (numb.charAt(a - 1) == ".") {
      do {
        counter++;
        a++;
      }
      while (!isNaN(numb.charAt(a)) && a < numb.length);
    }
    if (counter > highest) {
      highest = counter;
    }
    counter = 0;
  }
  return highest;
}


function add(clicked_className, Zeichen) {
  if (equalsPressed == false && clicked_className == 'zahlen') {
    window.document.Rechner.Display.value =
      window.document.Rechner.Display.value + Zeichen;
  } else if (dritter && equalsPressed && clicked_className == 'zahlen') {
    var array = new Array();
    array.push(window.document.Rechner.Display2.value + "=" +
      window.document.Rechner.Display.value);

    var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("Historie")
    var table = document.createElement('TABLE')
    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY')
    table.border = '0';
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);

    var td = document.createElement('TD')
    td.width = '275';
    td.style.textAlign = "right";
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[0]));

    tr.appendChild(td);
    myTableDiv.appendChild(table)


    window.document.Rechner.Display2.value = "";
    window.document.Rechner.Display.value = "";
    window.document.Rechner.Display.value =
      window.document.Rechner.Display.value + Zeichen;
    equalsPressed = false;

  } else if (equalsPressed && clicked_className == 'zahlen') {
    window.document.Rechner.Display2.value = "";
    window.document.Rechner.Display.value = "";
    window.document.Rechner.Display.value =
      window.document.Rechner.Display.value + Zeichen;
    equalsPressed = false;

  } else if (clicked_className == 'ops') {
    var x;
    window.document.Rechner.Display.value = window.document.Rechner.Display.value.replace("=", '');
    window.document.Rechner.Display.value =
      window.document.Rechner.Display.value + Zeichen;
    equalsPressed = false;
  }
}



function gleichPressed() {
  equalsPressed = true;
}


function backspace() {
  var abschneiden = window.document.Rechner.Display.value;
  for (var i = 0; i < abschneiden.length; i++) {
    var output = abschneiden.slice(0, -1);
    window.document.Rechner.Display.value = output;
  }
}

function ausgabe() {

  if (equalsPressed) {

  } else {

    array.push(window.document.Rechner.Display2.value +
      window.document.Rechner.Display.value);
    console.log(array);

    var myTableDiv = document.getElementById("Historie")
    var table = document.createElement('TABLE')
    var tableBody = document.createElement('TBODY')
    table.border = '0';
    table.appendChild(tableBody);
    var tr = document.createElement('TR');
    tableBody.appendChild(tr);

    var td = document.createElement('TD')
    td.width = '275';
    td.style.textAlign = "right";
    td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[0]));

    tr.appendChild(td);
    myTableDiv.appendChild(table)
  }
}
```

```css
body {
  font-family: "Century Gothic", CenturyGothic, Geneva, AppleGothic, sans-serif;
}

.button,
.ops,
.zahlen,
.sonst,
.istgleich {
  background-color: #A4A4A4;
  background: linear-gradient(240deg, grey, white);
  color: black;
  width: 60px;
  text-align: center;
  font-family: System, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}

.button:hover,
.zahlen:hover,
.sonst:hover,
.ops:hover,
.istgleich:hover {
  color: #2E2E2E;
  background-color: #FAFAFA;
  background: linear-gradient(30deg, darkgrey, lightgrey, grey);
  ;
}

.display {
  width: 100%;
  text-align: right;
  font-family: System, sans-serif;
  font-size: 100%;
}

#Historie {
  background: linear-gradient(30deg, silver, white, grey);
  ;
  border: 5px outset;
  float: left;
  text-align: right;
}

#eins {
  background: linear-gradient(30deg, silver, grey, DimGray);
  ;
}

#zwei {
  background: linear-gradient(90deg, silver, grey);
  ;
}

#tabelle {
  width: 300px;
  height: 235px;
  float: left;
}
```

```html
<html onmouseup="end()">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Taschenrechner</title>
</head>

<body bgcolor="#FFFFE0" text="#000000">
  <form name="Rechner" action="" onSubmit="Ergebnis();return false;">
    <table id="tabelle" style="float:left" border="7" cellpadding="12" cellspacing="0">
      <tr>
        <td id="eins">
          <input type="text" name="Display2" class="display" readonly>
          <input type="text" name="Display" class="display" readonly></td>
      </tr>

      <tr>
        <td id="zwei">

          <table border="1" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
            <tr>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value="  7   " onmouseleave="end()">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value="  8   " onmouseleave="end()">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value="  9   " onmouseleave="end()">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="sonst" value="  &#171  " onClick="backspace()">
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value="  4   " onmouseleave="end()">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value="  5   " onmouseleave="end()">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value="  6   " onmouseleave="end()">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="ops" value="  +   " onClick="add(this.className,'+')">
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value="  1   " onmouseleave="end()">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value="  2   " onmouseleave="end()">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value="  3   " onmouseleave="end()">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="ops" value="  -   " onClick="add(this.className,'-')">
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value="  .   ">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value="  0   " onmouseleave="end()">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="istgleich" value="  =   " onClick="Ergebnis();ausgabe();gleichPressed()">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="ops" value="  *   " onClick="add(this.className,'*')">
              </td>
            </tr>

            <tr>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value=" ( ">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="zahlen" value=" ) ">
              </td>
              <td><input type="reset" class="button" value="  C  ">
              </td>
              <td><input type="button" class="ops" value="  /   " onClick="add(this.className,'/')">
              </td>
            </tr>

          </table>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>

  <div class="Historie" id="Historie" hidden="true">
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: wow thanks very much <3 i will look through it now thoroughly!:)

Comment: but now the history on the right doesnt work properly anymore :( it always just shows the first result :/

Comment: :D it also didn't in the first place ;) my first guess would be this line to cause the error: `td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[0]));` but i'm not sure...

Comment: no its exactly right :)```td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(array[array.length-1]));``` fixed it

Comment: my next goal is re-aligning the text to right in the historie element after it changes size :)